# Nativescript: iOS Utils openFile

Tags: nativescript

I am working on code to open files which have been downloaded from the app, and I am using the utils.ios.openFile function. I can get the files to display on screen, however I am also getting the following warning on the console. Has anyone run into this, or have any ideas on how to resolve?

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   . Cannot find
>   preview item for proxy:  -
>   mobile-application.png (0)

The following is the code I am using:

```
var documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
filePath = fs.path.join(documents.path, filename);


if(fs.File.exists(filePath)){
    utilModule.ios.openFile(filePath)
    .catch(function(error){
    });
} else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("File not Found"));
}
```

Comment: Update: After testing some more, I noticed this warning message only appears under the ios 9.3, but when testing under 10.2 there is no warning message. In addition, under 9.3 the file is opened in full screenmode, with status and action bars hidden (while is 10.2 it is displayed). I suspect the message is related to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the filePath to the image, without using `openFile(filePath)` method. You could review the below-attached example.

```
let folder = fs.knownFolders.documents();
let path = fs.path.join(folder.path, "Test.png");
if(fs.File.exists(path )){
   image.src=path
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using openFile, because I need to open files of different types.